# pi 4 - Power present

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, power, power-supply, script

I am using a pi4 and pijuice.

Is it possible with a script or python to check if power is present in my Pi4?(usb port)

I am using my pi4 headless with as a web server(online). I would like to know from my terminal or added in my web page.

Comment: Have you looked at the [(*partial*) schematics?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/README.md) I know nothing of this `pijuice` gadget, but **if** it supplies power to the RPi through the GPIO, then the schematic suggests that the only way to do what you are asking is to measure *current* flow. Why? Measuring voltage on the `5V` bus will only show that there is voltage on the bus - it will not and **can not** tell the **source** of that voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pijuice library GetStatus() function should give you what you need:

https://github.com/PiSupply/PiJuice/blob/master/Software/README.md#pijuice-status

> GetStatus()
>
> Gets basic PiJuice status information about power inputs, battery and events.
>
> Returns:
>
> {'data':{
> 'isFault':is_fault,
> 'isButton':is_button,
> 'battery':battery_status,
> 'powerInput':power_input_status,
> 'powerInput5vIo':5v_power_input_status
> }}
>
> Where:
>
> is_fault is True if there are faults or fault events waiting to be read or False >if there are no faults and no fault events.
>
> is_button is True if there are button events, False if not.
>
> battery_status is a string constant that describes the current battery status, >one of four: 'NORMAL', 'CHARGING_FROM_IN', 'CHARGING_FROM_5V_IO', 'NOT_PRESENT'.
>
> power_input_status is a string constant that describes current status of USB Micro power input, one of four: 'NOT_PRESENT', 'BAD', 'WEAK', 'PRESENT'.
>
> 5v_power_input_status: is a string constant that describes current status of the >5V GPIO power input, one of four: 'NOT_PRESENT', 'BAD', 'WEAK', 'PRESENT'.
> Example:
>
> print(pijuice.status.GetStatus())
> Returns:
>
> {'data': {'battery': 'CHARGING_FROM_5V_IO', 'powerInput5vIo': 'PRESENT', >'isFault': False, 'isButton': False, 'powerInput': 'NOT_PRESENT'}, 'error': >'NO_ERROR'}

Comment: That's one solution. Is there any other solution, simple by checking usb C port for power?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, I believe the USB-C port is directly connected to the 5V and GND pins. So there would be no way to know which was connected.